# Bluetooth parallel connection

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have few question regarding the Bluetooth devices connectivity with one sender Bluetooth device and many receiver Bluetooth device

1. can one sender sends same files to many.
2. can one sender make many connection available at same time(not sending anything, just have connection availability).
3. with Bluetooth device, can we make both way communication(not one to one, like group chat).
4. Both sender and receiver can exchange the data at same time.IS it Possible?

thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't specific enough. Do you want to make smart phone app? if yes which platform?

Comment: You tagged your question as both `bluetooth` & `bluetooth-lowenergy`. These are two different things. Judging by your `core-bluetooth` tag you are targeting `iOS` and Bluetooth Low Energy?

Answer (score 0):

> can one sender sends same files to many.

Yes and No, Bluetooth does have capability to broadcast but most platforms does not provide Apis for it. 
One way to do it is for your application to repeat the same file fragment to all devices one after the other.

> can one sender make many connection available at same time(not sending anything, just have connection availability).

Yes

> with Bluetooth device, can we make both way communication(not one to one, like group chat).
>   Both sender and receiver can exchange the data at same time.IS it Possible?

Yes sure very much - Bluetooth I general can - how to do it for specific platforms and Bluetooth version is dependent on that particular platform and version